# Toolbar content looks different on preview mode than emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement custom Toolbar into my application. I want to have 1 image and 1 textview on the left, 1 textview in the middle and 1 textview in the end. In preview mode it looks as intended:
[image]
However, when I launch my application on virtual device, all views are aligned to the start:
[image]

My code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        tools:context=".OptionListActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nameSurname"
                android:text="June Office"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Dec 19, 12:47 PM"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateTime"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="415-555-1212"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

What do I need to change to get the intended result? And maybe someone could explain me why it looks good on preview mode and incorrect on emulator...

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with below code this may help you

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        tools:context=".OptionListActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=1>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nameSurname"
                android:text="June Office"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

         </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="Dec 19, 12:47 PM"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateTime"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="415-555-1212"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: in other xml file I needed to change layout_width from wrap_content to match_parent... Thanks for trying to help me...